# Python create a SQLlite3 table with primary key from DataFrame

Tags: python, database, pandas, sqlite, primary-key

I have a SQLlite3 database in python. I need to create a Table from a Pandas DataFrame as follow.

```
df.to_sql(name='Product', con=db, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

Now, I have a column called 'Id' in my 'Product' dataframe, that I want to define as the Primary Key.
The to_sql function doesn't have any parameter to define this kind of constraint on a column and I don't think that defining my Id column as an index of my dataframe will be sufficient. 
How could I elegantly define my Id colum as the PrimaryKey of my sqllite table in this case?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Added a new answer to that other question that might be of use if you don't like the other ones.

Comment: Great, Then creating an unique constraint should works on my case. This is an acceptable answer with documentation reference. Thanks a lot.